# How to create customize CreatePage.aspx in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, asp.net, aspx, sharepoint-ootb

I am new to Sharepoint, need some help here

When create a new page in the CreatePage.aspx we need to enter the url name, it will forbid the special characters(shown as pictures), but my problem is the check of special characters is too loose - it banned some of the special characters but not enough for me - I want some more restrictions here(i.e. ban the use of @)

I know that indexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName taking care of checking the special characters so I plan to write a custom code in the custom CreatePage.aspx file to restrict the use of special chars, but the issue is I am not able to customize the CreatePage.aspx in the first place.

I tried to copy the CreatePage.aspx file and rename it as CustomCreatePage.aspx, and put it within the same folder as the CreatePage.aspx. But when I try to open CustomCreatePage.aspx in the browser, it gives me error page showing "Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred."
Nothing much information from the error message...
But it is the exact same code with the original one, I don't understand why the custom one just doesn't work.

I guess in the end my question is, is it possible to create a custom CreatePage.aspx? If so, how to?

Thank you so much for time in advance!

[image: Special Characters Check]

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it's possible that you won't need to construct a new page; instead, you'll need to create an "`Event Receiver`" for the "`Pages`" Library's on "`ItemAdding`" event.

With this approach, you will be able to add your custom code without changing the default Create Page.

> Learn how to Create an event receiver at [SharePoint Event Receivers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-of-sharepoint-event-receivers/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately I am not able to install SP Server or SP Foundation on my laptop. I tried to use Visual Studio but it won't allow me to create project without having SP Server or Foundation installed..Is that the only way to create event receiver for my use case?